# Why muddialog and muddropzone not working together?

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop, dialog, mudblazor

I have a drag and drop and in the items i have an edit button open a muddialog:

```
private HashSet<SectionDropZoneItem> visible = new HashSet<SectionDropZoneItem>();
private void OpenDialog(SectionDropZoneItem context)
{
    visible.Add(context);       
    SectionMudDropContainerRef.Refresh();
}
```

And has an update method:

```
async Task Update(SectionDropZoneItem context)
{
    Section newSection = new Section { Name = newName, Description = newDescription };
    var oldSection = await repo.Section.GetAsync(context.Id);
    try
    {
        await repo.Section.UpdateAsync(newSection, oldSection);
        _sectionItems.Add(new SectionDropZoneItem { Zone = "Aktív modulok", Name = newName, Description = newDescription, DepartmentId = context.DepartmentId, DocumentId = context.DocumentId, Position = context.Position });
        _sectionItems.Remove(context);
        visible.Remove(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    SectionMudDropContainerRef.Refresh();
}
```

I think the problem is with the modiyfied context.
The _sectionItems.Remove(context) and visible.Remove(context) not working together. If im deleting one of theese the other one working, no matter visible or _sectionItems.

If you need this:

```
 <MudButton Class="" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="() => OpenDialog(context)" StartIcon="@MudBlazor.Icons.Material.Filled.Edit">Szerkesztés</MudButton>
 <MudDialog IsVisible="visible.Contains(context)" Options="dialogOptions">                                                
     <TitleContent>
         <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">
             <MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Edit" Class="mr-3" /> @context.Name szerkesztése
         </MudText>
     </TitleContent>
     <DialogContent>
         <MudTextField T="String" Value="@context.Name" ValueChanged="(string text) => newName = text" Label="Név" Variant="Variant.Text" Required="true"/>
         <MudTextField T="String" Value="@context.Description" ValueChanged="(string text) => newDescription = text" Label="Leírás" Variant="Variant.Text" />                                                        
     </DialogContent>
     <DialogActions>
         <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="(() => Close(context))" Class="px-10">Close</MudButton>
         <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="(() => Update(context))" Class="px-10">Update</MudButton>
     </DialogActions>
 </MudDialog>

    private class SectionDropZoneItem
    {
        public string Zone { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; init; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; init; }
        public int DocumentId { get; init; }
        public string Description { get; init; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    async Task Update(SectionDropZoneItem context)
    {
        try{
            var item = _sectionItems.FirstOrDefault(i => i.DocumentId == context.DocumentId && i.DepartmentId == context.DepartmentId && i.Id == context.Id && i.Name == context.Name && i.Description == context.Description && i.Zone == context.Zone);
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.Name = newName;
                item.Description = newDescription;                
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        Section newSection = new Section { Name = newName, Description = newDescription };
        var oldSection = await repo.Section.GetAsync(context.Id);
        try
        {
            await repo.Section.UpdateAsync(newSection, oldSection);           
            visible.Remove(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        SectionMudDropContainerRef.Refresh();
    }
```

This is the solution, now im not remove and add a new list item, im search the list item and overwrite.